# Magento add extra field to existing section in system.xml

Tags: magento2

How can we add an extra field to an existing section in the child module in Magento 2?

Here is the code in parent module/

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="section_id">
            <group id="my_config" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Demo Label</label>
                <comment><![CDATA[]]></comment>
                <attribute type="expanded">1</attribute>
                <group id="group_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="600" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Demo label</label>
                    <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Enabled</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>                    
                </group>

<----------Add new group using the child module-------------->  


            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="section_id" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="my_config">
                <group id="group_id_2" translate="label" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                       showInStore="1">
                    <label>Custom new field group</label>
                    <field id="my_custom_text" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                           showInStore="1">
                        <label>My custom text</label>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

of course you will have to add the field type you want, edit labels and ids that you need there :).

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="ProductQty" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Qty Increment</label>
            <tab>vendor</tab>
            <resource>vendor_module::ProductQty_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Enable module</label>
                    <validate>validate-select</validate>
                    <comment>Select Yes to enable this module</comment>
                    <source_model>\Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

magento how can admin select custom field product "sku", able to Change "price", "sale price" and a button for "update price" dynamically.

[Magento2 admin select custom field product "SKU" and change "price", "sale price"" and a button for "update price" dynamically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/366258/magento2-admin-select-custom-field-product-sku-and-change-price-sale-price)